# Wordpress to generate WP_Error Object for user login?

Tags: wordpress, object, authentication, error-handling

I want to return the Login Error Message even user key-in their privileges correctly. In other words, to terminate the login and show the error message.

When we key-in wrong passwords, wordpress shows:

```
There was an error authenticating your details.

ERROR: The password you entered for the username admin is incorrect. Lost your password?
```

.. on the login page. This is because of `WP_Error` Object is returned.

So my curious question is:

- How to get/generate this `WP_Error` Object on my own, to return back? Is it Array?

Comment: how to retrieve error in custom template with custom login form..please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066775/how-to-retrieve-wp-error-in-custom-login-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook into the authenticate wordpress hook.  Then return a new WP_Error object to generate an error message and redirect back to the login page.  Here is an example.

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login_submit', 40, 3);

function check_login_submit($user, $username, $password) {
    $WP_Error = new WP_Error();
    $WP_Error->add('my_error', '<strong>Error</strong>: Something went wrong.');
    return $WP_Error;
}
```