# how to retrieve wp error in custom login form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create template for login with help of `wp_login_form()` function.
Now If user enter wrong password or username it will redirect me to the same page with argument `login=failed` with the following code :

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'front_end_login_fail' );
function front_end_login_fail( $username ) {

$_SESSION['uname'] =  $username;
// Getting URL of the login page
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];    
$login_failed_error_codes = array( 'empty_password', 'empty_email', 'invalid_email', 'invalidcombo', 'empty_username', 'invalid_username', 'incorrect_password' );

// if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
if( !empty( $referrer ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 93 ) . "?login=failed" ); 
    exit;
}

}
```

NOW this function works ok but now as per **wordpress** functionality which provide as follow:

1.If user enter **true** username but **wrong** password it will show error as **"incorrect_password"**

2.If user enter **false** username but **true** password it will show error as **"invalid_username"**

3.If user enter **wrong** username but **wrong** password it will show error as **"invalidcombo"**

Add so on please check variable  **$login_failed_error_codes** in code...
I have made some search.I got some class called "WP_error".But I dont know how it works with this code.

I am just stuck in how to pass object of WP_error from wp-login.php to my csutom template?

Thanks...any help would be appriciable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. You want to be able to display the reason login failed on your own custom login page. I assume you already know how to fetch the `$_GET` parameters, since you are using that to pass your `login_failed` parameter.

Use the `login_redirect` filter instead:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user) {
    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        //Login failed, find out why...
        $error_types = array_keys($user->errors);
        //Error type seems to be empty if none of the fields are filled out
        $error_type = 'both_empty';
        //Otherwise just get the first error (as far as I know there
        //will only ever be one)
        if (is_array($error_types) && !empty($error_types)) {
            $error_type = $error_types[0];
        }
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 93 ) . "?login=failed&reason=" . $error_type ); 
        exit;
    } else {
        //Login OK - redirect to another page?
        return home_url();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the exact  wp-login error message? I wanted to get the account locked time duration in case of max i failed login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created custom template for login then Why don't you use [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) method with the help of custom form ?. it will return WP_error object on false, and on true it will return $user object.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['user_email'];
        $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['user_password'];
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        if ( is_wp_error($user) )
            echo $user->get_error_message();
}
?>

<form id="user-credentials" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <p><input name="user_email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></p>
    <p><input name="user_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

I've not tested in but it should work.

Comment: thx ..really appriciate your effort.but I used wp_login_form() function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16534887/524743) is what you need:

> You need to hook into the authenticate wordpress hook. Then return a
>   new WP_Error object to generate an error message and redirect back to
>   the login page. Here is an example.

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login_submit', 40, 3);

function check_login_submit($user, $username, $password) {
    $WP_Error = new WP_Error();
    $WP_Error->add('my_error', '<strong>Error</strong>: Something went wrong.');
    return $WP_Error;
}
```

Comment: Thx. for response but i am just stuck in how to pass object of WP_error from wp-login.php to my csutom template?

Comment: You don't have to pass object. Just pass error message and error code. Then you can create new WP_Error object like this: `$my_error = new WP_Error( 'ErrorCode', 'ErrorMessage' );`

Comment: if possible give example.

Comment: So do you want WordPress errors instead of your custom errors?

Comment: nope not exactly.I want to default use wordpress default error concept..not by creating custom error class...

Comment: I am having the exact same problem as vrajesh, however, I think there is some misunderstanding due to language barriers here. The problem is that there is not a clear way of passing the error messages that are generated by WordPress to the custom script. Ideally it would be nice to have a way to pass the WP_error object that is generated inside the wp_login.php file directly to the custom script, but I think it may fall out of scope if you try to use it that way. Maybe there is a trick to safely store it as a temporary global variable that can be accessed by the custom code?

Comment: But safety is a concern! That would be option one... Another option might be to just pass the the error message and error code as Samuel suggested above, but he did not include an example for how to do that exactly. One possibility would be to inject the error code and message in the redirect URL so that it can be referenced by your custom code upon redirect to your custom page. I have seen this injection concept described briefly above, and a little better here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21765/redirect-to-custom-url-when-registration-fails .

Comment: But I don't like the idea of sticking the entire message in the URL, and there are at least 50 different error messages (throughout various parts of login/registration/password-reset sections) that would have to be rewritten to the custom script if only the error code (not the message) was included in the URL; so for that reason, not passing the entire error message is just not practical. There must be a good way to pass these messages to the custom code upon redirect; but how? That is the real problem; and so far I have not seen any great solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
 $set_confirm=0;
$_SESSION['uname'] =  $username;
/*******Check whether user entered username or email to login*********/
if(is_email( $username ) ){
       if( email_exists( $username )) {
           $uid = email_exists( $username );
           $confirm_mail =get_user_meta($uid,'confirm_mail',true);
           if($confirm_mail!=1){
                $set_confirm=1;
            }
       }
    //$user_check = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
    //print_r($user_check);

}else{

    if ( username_exists( $username ) ){
         $uid = username_exists( $username );
           $confirm_mail =get_user_meta($uid,'confirm_mail',true);
          if($confirm_mail!=1){
               $set_confirm=1;
            }       
    }
}
    //$user_check = get_user_by( 'user_login ', $username );
    //print_r($user_check);

// Getting URL of the login page
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];    


// if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
if( !empty( $referrer ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && !strstr( $referrer,'wp-admin' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( 93 ) . "?login=failed&confirm_email=".$set_confirm); 
    exit;
}

}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'front_end_login_fail' );
```

Comment: This chunk of code just determines "whether user entered username or email to login", then injects "&confirm_email=1" or "0" accordingly... It does not solve the problem for how to pass full error messages to the custom script.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this way it worked for me

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
   {
            foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_val) 
                {   
                  echo $sub_val; 
                }                         
    }
```